# If there wasn't a weak nuclear force, what would be the heaviest stable theoretically stable isotope with equal protons and neutrons?

Tags: nuclear-physics, stability, weak-interaction, elements, isotopes

If there was no weak nuclear force, what would be the heaviest stable theoretically stable isotope with equal protons and Neutrons? For our universe the heaviest such isotope is calcium 40, but most heavier such isotopes decay by electron capture or positron emission, processes that don't exist in this scenario.